# How to edit tag subscription email frequency

Tags: support, tags, email, preferences

I have subscribed to receive emails for new questions on several tags on Stack Overflow, and in the resulting web page was able to set the frequency that emails are sent. But now, I can't figure out how to get  back to edit those settings, short of unsubscribing and subscribing again.

So my question is: How do I set/change the email frequency for tags that I have subscribed to?

Comment: I have the same issue (mentioned above). When i go to my favorite tag URL i.e. http://stackexchange.com/filters/xxxxx/favorite-tags, mid right of page it says email frequency with a "edit" link but doesn't direct you anywhere. ps using firefox v12/IE9

Comment: Screenshot of what I mean: (http://i.stack.imgur.com/GYVmV.jpg)

Comment: You can find instructions in [this equivalent post on meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281610/how-do-i-change-the-frequency-of-the-favorite-tags-email).